# Version control best practices for libraries with SONAME

Tags: version-control, filenames, perforce

I am creating packages and libraries for Linux which include the package or library version in the filename, a [soname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname).
What is the current best practice for handling this with version control?  Typically, version control will maintain a repository of versioned files which are mapped to a user's workspace.
We all know that song and dance:

```
//repo/myfile.txt#1     //ws/myfile.txt
```

But this gets cumbersome when I work with versioned libraries.

```
//repo/libs/my-library.so.1.0#1    //ws/libs/my-library.so.1.0
//repo/libs/my-library.so.1.1#1    //ws/libs/my-library.so.1.1
. . . 
//repo/libs/my-library.so.3.0#1    //ws/libs/my-library.so.3.0
```

I don't necessarily need every version of a package when I perform a get latest on my repo., just the most recent.  Also, the entire point of a version control system is to remove this hassle from the developer. However, users do in fact need the versioned filename when distributing these libraries.

Is there perhaps a way to tell my version control system to perform the map like this?

```
//repo/libs/my-library.so#1     //ws/libs/my-library.so.1.0
//repo/libs/my-library.so#2     //ws/libs/my-library.so.1.1
. . . 
//repo/libs/my-library.so#30    //ws/libs/my-library.so.3.0
```

In my specific, subjective use case, I am using Perforce for version control.  However I am mainly curious about the general best practice, not just a hack for Perforce to accomplish this if it is entirely a dumb approach.

Comment: What's the significance of the `:` in your example?  Did you mean to use `#` to indicate different revisions?

Comment: Are you storing shared libraries in your repository?  Doing that isn't a best practice.

Comment: @Samwise, yes the repo path followed by `:1` is the file revision number.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: @bk2204 yes, I am storing shared libraries that my development team is creating in our repository, along with application binaries and ipk files used by our system package managers.  We have to maintain large networks of distributed systems and it is a business requirement that we are able to maintain old versions in case technicians screw something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a soname describes the version of a library's interface, rather than its implementation, it corresponds roughly to a "release" in terms of software lifecycle management.  In most version control systems (including Perforce), that means you want to represent it as some form of branch (each of which may have an arbitrary number of revisions corresponding to implementation changes) rather than mapping each individual revision/commit to its own soname.

Perforce's inter-file branching system makes this very easy to model -- when it's time to rev the soname, you branch the file to its new name, just like you'd naturally use `cp` if you weren't using version control.  (Unlike git, you don't have to branch the entire repo all as a unit; each individual file can have its own branching structure if you want, and the variants are represented within the client filesystem as well as in the repo.)

If your current project needs a particular soname variant and you don't want to pull down all the others when you sync, set up your client view to only map the one you want.